# why my url doesn't work without www and shows 404 not found page?

Tags: url, web, dns

I recently changed my DNS and now when I type my URL without www the web browser shows the 404 Error.

these are my URLs:

http://www.varzide.info

http://varzide.info

what can I do to solve this problem? Is this error from default name systems?

Answer (score -1):

Clearing your cache may solve the problem.Try this if you are using windows.

1. Click the Microsoft Vista Start logo in the bottom left corner of the screen
2. Click All Programs
3. Click Accessories
4. RIGHT-click on Command Prompt
5. Select Run As Administrator
6. In the command window type the following and then hit enter: ipconfig /flushdns
7. You will see the following confirmation:

more info [**HERE**](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/ClearingBrowserCache)

Comment: I tried that but yet I have the problem.http://varzide.info redirects to http://varzide.info/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi

Comment: have you tried restarting your computer? just updated my answer for more info. also you can add this to your htaccess 'RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]' so that the site can be access always with a 'www'

Comment: oh dear. thank you very much. I forgot restarting the computer. now the URL works well.